# How to factorize $zz^*-4z-4z^*+12=0$ (where $z^*$ is the complex conjugate of $z$)

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

I'm trying to factorize this:
$$zz^*-4z-4z^*+12=0$$
to get this:
$$|z-4|^2 - 4 = 0$$
where $z=x+yi$ is a complex number and $z^*=x-yi$ is the conjugate complex number of $z$.

I'm trying to factorise this using the completed square method but had no luck so far.

Could use some help.

Comment: Note that $zz^*-4z-4z^*+12=0\implies zz^*-4z-4z^*+16=4 \implies z(z^*-4)-4(z^*-4)-4=0 \implies (z-4)(z^*-4)-4=0.$ Also note that $zz^*=|z|^2$ so $(z-4)(z^*-4)-4=0 \implies |z-4|^2-4=0$

Comment: Alright, got it now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
zz^* -4z -4z^* +12 &= zz^* -4z -4z^* +16 -4\\
&= z(z^* -4) -4(z^* -4) -4\\
&= (z-4)(z^* -4) -4\\
&= (z-4)(z-4)^* -4\\
&= |z-4|^2 -4. 
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Remark, since $zz^*=x^2+y^2$ and $z+z^*=2x$ you can as well write

$zz^*-4z-4z^*+12=x^2+y^2-8x+12=(x-4)^2+y^2-4=|z-4|^2-4=0$

Since both represent the equation of a circle of centre $(4,0)$ and radius $2$.